# How to add new column to a table in Cassandra? When a SyntaxException occurs?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cql, cassandra-3.0

I was trying to add new column to table in Cassandra, but an error occurred and I have no idea what it means.

This is the code I used:

```js
ALTER TABLE ksiazki 
ADD id_autorow set;
```

The error I got:

```js
SyntaxException: line 1:38 mismatched input ';' expecting '<' ( . . . table ksiazki add id_autorow set [;])
```

[This is a picture which shows how the table looks and which error pops out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22K8f.png)

Comment: I don't know Cassandra but I think it has a problem with "set". What is "set" supposed to be? According to the docs, you should specify the new column name and then data type. Is "set" a data type? Maybe it requires "diamond notation" like the example - list<text> - https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/cql/cql/cql_reference/cql_commands/cqlAlterTable.html

Answer (score 1):

So the error message says it’s expecting a `<`, because sets need their base data type at time of declaration.  For example, if you wanted to add a set of type `TEXT`, you’d alter your statement to this:

```
ALTER TABLE ksiazki 
ADD id_autorow set<TEXT>;
```

Comment: @DefinitelyNotAHacker Excellent!  Glad I could help.